# Having some trouble creating a UserControl with a parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, parent

I use a `TabControl` in one of my classes. However, I don't want to bloat this class and put all the code in it, as well as all the `XAML` for the TabItems.

After some Googling I've come up with the `UserControl`. So I created a `UserControl` for every `TabItem`, with the C# code of the `TabItem` in this `UserControl`.

The problem here, is that I need to transfer some data from my parent window (the one containing the `TabControl`) to the `UserControls`, to correctly display the data needed for that tab.

I created the `UserControl` in `XAML` and the code is like this:

```
<TabItem Name="userTab" Header="Gebruikers" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <local:UserTabControl x:Name="userTabPanel"/>
</TabItem>
```

This is the constructor code for my `UserControl`:

```
public UserTabControl() {
        setUsersView(); // NEED DATA FOR THIS
        setUserData((User)usersView.SelectedItem);
        InitializeComponent();
 }
```

This is the class variable in the `UserControl` that needs a variable from the parent window: `private static Parser m_config;`

When I run this, I get a compile error saying :

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

pointing to the XAML line where I create my UserControl.

So, the conclusion here is I am yet unable to pass the variable to the UserControl and would like to have some suggestions or hints or guidance on how to do it in this case. Where am I going wrong here in achieving the required functionality ?

Comment: The UserControl should expose a dependency property that could be bound to a view model property. Search the web for MVVM and WPF Data Binding.

Comment: You can always create Public methods in your User Control that accept parameters and invoke them.

Comment: I would not populate the control in the constructor. At that stage you only create the object. Then you can inject dependencies, bind dependency properties, do data binding and the like. In some applications I have used the service locator pattern so that application and UI logic can access infrastructure services like data access.

Comment: Are you getting that error at runtime or design time?

Comment: Conrad, I'm getting the error at design time. Christoph, I'm quite new to C#, so no idea what dependencies and data binding, going to google it now! Abhinav, tried that, unfortunately I have no idea how I can call public methods in my UserControl. Clemens, i'm going to check it out, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure that its the best way to do so, but for me it worked well.

For start I create **CustomUserControl** Class that inherit from **UserControl** with constractor that get his parent Form as an attribute like this:

```
public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{
   MainForm parentForm;
   public CustomUserControl(MainForm mainForm)
   {
      parentForm = mainForm;
   }
   ... 
   ...
   private void doSomthing()
   {
      parentForm.MainFormMember = 1;
   }
}
```

And in the MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   private int MainFormMember{ get; set; }
   private CustomUserControl customUserControl;

   public MainForm()
   {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create and add the CustomUserControl manually and not from ToolBox
        customUserControl = new CustomUserControl(this);
        this.Controls.Add(customUserControl);
   }

   ...
   ...
}
```

In this way you can access the Form components from the UserControl

Comment: I'm not going to do it that way. The UserControl shouldn't have knowledge of its parent window in my opinion!